# Why is $GL(n, \Bbb R)$ open in the Zariski topology?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry, lie-groups

The general linear group $GL(n,\mathbb{R})$ is said to have Zariski topology, but I do not understand how. Can anyone explain this to me?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Zariski topology is a topology well-suited to the study of algebraic varieties, the principal objects of study in algebraic geometry:

> For any field $\Bbb F$, a set $X \subseteq \Bbb F^n$ is defined to be closed in the Zariski topology on iff it has the form $$V(S) := \{(x_1, \ldots, x_n) \in \Bbb F^n : f(x_1, \ldots, x_n) = 0 \,\forall f \in S\}$$ for some set $S$ of polynomials $f_a(x_1, \ldots, x_n) \in \Bbb F[x_1, \ldots, x_n]$.

The general linear group $GL(n, \Bbb F)$ is usually defined to be set of invertible $n \times n$ matrices over $\Bbb F$, that is, the $n \times n$ matrices with nonzero determinant. On the other hand, the determinant map $\det: M(n, \Bbb F) \to \Bbb F$ is a polynomial in the entries $x_{11}, \ldots, x_{nn}$ of the argument matrix $X$, where $M(n, \Bbb F)$ is the space of $n \times n$ matrices over $\Bbb F$, which we can identify with $\Bbb F^{n^2}$ in the obvious way. Thus, the set $$V(\{\det\}) := \{X \in M(n, \Bbb F) : \det X = 0\} \subset M(n, \Bbb R) \cong \Bbb F^{n^2}$$ is closed in the Zariski topology, and hence its complement, namely, $$V(\{\det\})^c = \{X \in M(n, \Bbb F) : \det X \neq 0\} = GL(n, \Bbb F),$$ is open in the topology.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the space of all n-by-n matrices with entries in field F itself admits the structure of an affine space and hence also admits the Zariski topology.  The general linear group is, as the previous poster said, a Zariski-open subset of the affine space.  The general linear group may *itself* be given the subspace topology induced from the Zariski topology on the affine space, and in this way, the general linear group may be said to "have" the Zariski topology.