# open immersion $\operatorname{Spec}\left(\mathcal{O}_{\operatorname{GL}_n(k)}\right)\to\operatorname{Spec}\left(\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{A}^{n^2}}\right)$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $K$ be an algebraically closed field. Show that there is a map $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{A}^{n^2}}\to\mathcal{O}_{\operatorname{GL}_n(k)}$ which induces an open immersion $$\operatorname{Spec}\left(\mathcal{O}_{\operatorname{GL}_n(k)}\right)\to\operatorname{Spec}\left(\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{A}^{n^2}}\right).$$

I know that need he following theorem and the definition of open immersion.

If $\phi:A\to B$ is a homomorphism of rings, then $\phi$ induces a natural morphism of locally ringed spaces $$(f,f^{\text{#}}):(\operatorname{Spec}B,\mathcal{O}_{\operatorname{Spec}B})\to(\operatorname{Spec}A,\mathcal{O}_{\operatorname{Spec}A}).$$

Let $f:X\to Y$ is a morphism of locally ringed spaces. We say that $f$ is an open immersion if it is a homeomorphism from $X$ onto an open subset of $Y$, and the map $f^{-1}\mathcal{O}_Y\to\mathcal{O}_X$ is an isomorphism.

But,

1. What is the homomorphism from $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{A}^{n^2}}\to\mathcal{O}_{\operatorname{GL}_n(k)}$?
2. Why is $f:\operatorname{Spec}\left(\mathcal{O}_{\operatorname{GL}_n(k)}\right)\to\operatorname{Spec}\left(\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{A}^{n^2}}\right)$ a homeomorphism from $\operatorname{Spec}\left(\mathcal{O}_{\operatorname{GL}_n(k)}\right)$ to an open subset of $\operatorname{Spec}\left(\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{A}^{n^2}}\right)$?
3. Why is $f^{-1}\operatorname{Spec}\left(\mathcal{O}_{\operatorname{GL}_n(k)}\right)\to\operatorname{Spec}\left(\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{A}^{n^2}}\right)$ an isomorphism?

Can somebody please help me and please elaborate your statements.

Comment: First, what would you expect the answer to be? That is, can you think of a connection between $GL_n$ and $\Bbb A^{n^2}$? $n\times n$ matrices have $n^2$ entries, and a matrix is invertible iff it's determinant doesn't vanish, so...? Secondly, you've got a lot of extra wrapping on this problem right now - no need to write $\operatorname{Spec}\mathcal{O}_{\Bbb A^{n^2}}$, you can just say $\Bbb A^{n^2}$. Thirdly, this result or things like it [have been discussed plenty on MSE in the past](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1386251/) - did you check any of those out?

Comment: @KReiser How can you say that $\operatorname{Spec}\mathcal{O}_{\Bbb A^{n^2}}$  is just $\Bbb A^{n^2}$ how can we explain it?

Comment: @Jale'dejaled That's the characterizing property of affine schemes. Check any introductory textbook - Hartshorne proposition II.2.2, Vakil remark 4.3.2, etc.

Comment: But the thing is we have locally ringed space here as $(\mathbb{A}^{n^2}, \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{A}^{n^2}})$

not $(Spec\mathbb{A}^{n^2}, \mathcal{O}_{spec \mathbb{A}^{n^2}})$

But that case it would be nonsense talk about spec at the end anyway right? I think there is a problem with the question statement.

Comment: Try explicitly writing out $\mathcal{O}_{\mathrm{GL}_{n,k}}$, and it might then become a little clearer what to do. If this is confusing, start by writing out $\mathcal{O}_{\mathrm{GL}_{1,k}}$ and then try to generalize.

Comment: What do you mean by $\operatorname{Spec} \mathcal{O}_X$? Usually, you take Spec of rings rather than sheaves of rings unless you mean relative Spec.

Answer (score -1):

**Question:** But,

1. What is the homomorphism from $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{A}^{n^2}}\to\mathcal{O}_{\operatorname{GL}_n(k)}$?

**Answer question 1:** Let $A:=k[x_{ij}:i,j\in\{1,..,n\}]$ and let $g:=det(x_{ij})$ denote the determinant of the "generic" $n\times n$-matrix with the variable $x_{ij}$ in the place $(i,j)$. Let $R:=A[t]/(det(x_{ij}t-1) \cong A_g$ where $A_g$ is the localization at the multiplicative subset $S_g:=\{1,g,g^2,..,\}\subseteq A$. It follows the canonical map

$$A \rightarrow A[t]/(gt-1)$$

equals the map

$$H^0(\mathbb{A}^{n^2}, \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{A}^{n^2}})\to  H^0(GL_n(k),   \mathcal{O}_{\operatorname{GL}_n(k)}).$$

There is a map of affine schemes $\phi: GL_n(k):=Spec(R) \rightarrow Spec(A):=\mathbb{A}^{n^2}$ which is an open immersion: It identifies $GL_n(k)$ with the basic open subscheme $D(g)\subseteq \mathbb{A}^{n^2}$. This gives a map of structure sheaves

$$\phi^{\#}: \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{A}^{n^2}}\to  \phi_* \mathcal{O}_{\operatorname{GL}_n(k)}.$$

2. Why is $f:\operatorname{Spec}\left(\mathcal{O}_{\operatorname{GL}_n(k)}\right)\to\operatorname{Spec}\left(\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{A}^{n^2}}\right)$ a homeomorphism from $\operatorname{Spec}\left(\mathcal{O}_{\operatorname{GL}_n(k)}\right)$ to an open subset of $\operatorname{Spec}\left(\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{A}^{n^2}}\right)$?

**Answer question 2:** Begause $GL_n(k) \cong D(g)$ which is a basic open subscheme of $Spec(A)$.

3. Why is $f^{-1}\operatorname{Spec}\left(\mathcal{O}_{\operatorname{GL}_n(k)}\right)\to\operatorname{Spec}\left(\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{A}^{n^2}}\right)$ an isomorphism?

**Answer question 3:** Corresponding to the map

$$\phi^{\#}:\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{A}^{n^2}} \rightarrow \phi_*\mathcal{O}_{\operatorname{GL}_n(k)}$$

there is a map

$$\phi^{*}:\phi^{-1}(\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{A}^{n^2}})\to \mathcal{O}_{\operatorname{GL}_n(k)}$$

which is an isomorphism:

The map  $\phi$ is an open immersion and

$$\phi^{-1}(\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{A}^{n^2}})\cong (\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{A}^{n^2}})_{D(g)} \cong \mathcal{O}_{D(g)} \cong \mathcal{O}_{\operatorname{GL}_n(k)}.$$

By definition $GL_n(k)$ is the complement $D(g)$ of the hypersurface $g:=det(x_{ij})$ in $\mathbb{A}^{n^2}$: It is set theoretically the "set of matrices with non-zero determinant" $det(x_{ij})\neq 0$. If $G:=GL_n(k)$ it follows the $k$-rational points

$$Hom_{Sch/k}(Spec(k), G):=G(k)\cong Hom_{k-alg}(R,k)$$

corresponds 1-1 to matrices $A:=(a_{ij})$ with $a_{ij}\in k$ and $det(A)\neq 0$. Hence the $k$-rational points of $G$ correspond to invertible matrices
and elements in the classical general linear group $GL(n,k)$.